# Bounded Buffer problem using semaphores in Linux

Tags: linux, semaphore, paging

I'm trying to understand the bounded buffer problem(consumer/producer) more clearly, As I know one of the solutions to this problem is using 3 semaphores 
1. FULL-which holds full places in the array
2. EMPTY-which holds the available places in the array
3. MUTEX-which holds number 1 or 0

could it be possible to explain further what does that mean for example if the number of FULL is negative? or the number of empty is negative?

Could that be that mutex will not be 1 or 0? if so what does that mean?

Comment: Page faults and semaphores are orthogonal.

Comment: I know but instead of making two different posts. I posted both the questions here.

Comment: This is not how this site works. One question per question please.

Comment: edited, Do you have any answer to the question?

Comment: Semaphores are never negative by design, so it does not mean anything at all. If you attempt to decrease a semaphore below 0, the operation will block. If you use a proper mutex, then there are no 0 or 1, there is a locked state and an unlocked state. If you use a semaphore as a mutex, which you generally should not because they are designed for different purposes, then indeed it is always 0 (locked) or 1 (unlocked).